# Image slideshow disappeared and wrong image size in Product page Prestashop

Tags: css, image, slideshow, prestashop-1.6

Sorry, if I may make some mistakes, I'm quite new so I will try to make this question as precise as I can.

**Here is the situation:**

In this website we have a product display page, with a full size image on the left with a module - Magictoolbox container - that allows me to have a zoom on the product image when the cursors is pointed it.

Normally, on the right hand side of this image we have a vertical slideshow, with smaller images.

Today the vertical slideshow from the product page disappeared and the dimensions are completely off:

https://www.backlabel.com/lounge/272-lounge-wear-pants.html

Here is the code related to product.tpl (I guess it's the correct file to look at)

My prestashop version is 1.6.1.17

---

```
        <div class="image_container"> 

        <div id="image-block" class="clearfix{if isset($images) && count($images) < 2} fwdth{/if}">

            {if $product->on_sale}

                <span class="sale-box">

                    <span class="sale-label">{l s='Sale!'}</span>

                </span>

            {elseif $product->specificPrice && $product->specificPrice.reduction && $productPriceWithoutReduction > $productPrice}

                <span class="discount">{l s='Reduced price!'}</span>

            {/if} 



            {if $have_image}

                <span id="view_full_size">

                    {if $jqZoomEnabled && $have_image && !$content_only}

                        <a class="jqzoom" title="{if !empty($cover.legend)}{$cover.legend|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{else}{$product->name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{/if}" rel="gal1" href="{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $cover.id_image, 'thickbox_'|cat:$cookie->img_name)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" itemprop="url">

                            <img itemprop="image" src="{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $cover.id_image, 'large_'|cat:$cookie->img_name)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{if !empty($cover.legend)}{$cover.legend|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{else}{$product->name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{/if}" alt="{if !empty($cover.legend)}{$cover.legend|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{else}{$product->name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{/if}"/>

                        </a>

                    {else}

                        <img id="bigpic" itemprop="image" src="{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $cover.id_image, 'large_'|cat:$cookie->img_name)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{if !empty($cover.legend)}{$cover.legend|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{else}{$product->name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{/if}" alt="{if !empty($cover.legend)}{$cover.legend|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{else}{$product->name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{/if}" width="{$largeSize.width}" height="{$largeSize.height}"/>

                        {if !$content_only}

                            <span class="span_link no-print">{l s='View larger'}</span>

                        {/if}

                    {/if}

                </span>

            {else}

                <span id="view_full_size">

                    <img itemprop="image" src="{$img_prod_dir}{$lang_iso}-default-large_{$cookie->img_name}.jpg" id="bigpic" alt="" title="{$product->name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" width="{$largeSize.width}" height="{$largeSize.height}"/>

                    {if !$content_only}

                        <span class="span_link">

                            {l s='View larger'}

                        </span>

                    {/if}

                </span>

            {/if}

        </div> <!-- end image-block -->



        {if isset($images) && count($images) > 0}

            <!-- thumbnails -->

            <div id="views_block" class="clearfix {if isset($images) && count($images) < 2}hidden{/if}">

                {if isset($images) && count($images) > 3}

                    <span class="view_scroll_spacer">

                        <a id="view_scroll_left" class="btn" title="{l s='Other views'}" href="javascript:{ldelim}{rdelim}">

                            {l s='Previous'}

                        </a>

                    </span>

                {/if}

                <div id="thumbs_list">

                    <ul id="thumbs_list_frame">

                    {if isset($images)}

                        {foreach from=$images item=image name=thumbnails}

                            {assign var=imageIds value="`$product->id`-`$image.id_image`"}

                            {if !empty($image.legend)}

                                {assign var=imageTitle value=$image.legend|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}

                            {else}

                                {assign var=imageTitle value=$product->name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}

                            {/if}

                            <li id="thumbnail_{$image.id_image}"{if $smarty.foreach.thumbnails.last} class="last"{/if}>

                                <a 

                                    {if $jqZoomEnabled && $have_image && !$content_only}

                                        href="javascript:void(0);"

                                        rel="{literal}{{/literal}gallery: 'gal1', smallimage: '{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $imageIds, 'large_'|cat:$cookie->img_name)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}',largeimage: '{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $imageIds, 'thickbox_'|cat:$cookie->img_name)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}'{literal}}{/literal}"

                                    {else}

                                        href="{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $imageIds, 'thickbox_'|cat:$cookie->img_name)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}"

                                        data-fancybox-group="other-views"

                                        class="thickbox{if $image.id_image == $cover.id_image} shown{/if}"

                                    {/if}

                                    title="{$imageTitle}">

                                    <img

                                        class="img-responsive"

                                        id="thumb_{$image.id_image}"

                                        src="{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $imageIds, 'medium_'|cat:$cookie->img_name)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}"

                                        alt="{$imageTitle}"

                                        title="{$imageTitle}"

                                        height="{$mediumSize.height}"

                                        width="{$mediumSize.width}"

                                        itemprop="image" />

                                </a>

                            </li>

                        {/foreach}

                    {/if}

                    </ul>

                </div> <!-- end thumbs_list -->

                {if isset($images) && count($images) > 3}

                    <a id="view_scroll_right" class="btn" title="{l s='Other views'}" href="javascript:{ldelim}{rdelim}">

                        {l s='Next'}

                    </a>

                {/if}

            </div> <!-- end views-block -->

            <!-- end thumbnails -->

        {/if}



        {if isset($images) && count($images) > 1}

            <p class="resetimg clear">

                <span id="wrapResetImages" style="display: none;">

                    <a id="resetImages" href="{$link->getProductLink($product)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">

                        <i class="icon-repeat"></i>

                        {l s='Display all pictures'}

                    </a>

                </span>

            </p>

        {/if}           

    </div><!-- end image_column -->}
```

I am really desperate and I don't know how to fix it, anyone has any idea?
Thank you all

Comment: I can't help you with the slideshow, but if you want a quick solution to let it look a bit better add `width: 100%; height: 100%;` to `div.MagicToolboxSelectorsContainer a` and add `width: 100%; height: auto;` to `#pb-right-column #image-block img` in your css file. This doesn't fix the slideshow but at least temporary fixes the image sizes

Comment: Thank you, I tried to quickly fix it to make it look better according to your instructions. The page however should look like [link] (https://www.backlabel.com/resort/279-cardigan-milk-protein-fibre.html), I hope I will be able to fix it!